# Microservice architectute and high availability and scalability for scheduler

Tags: java, spring, architecture, quartz-scheduler, spring-cloud

i'm trying to make a microservice architecture using spring cloud, for that I use config server, eureka and etc, also I exploit the docker to deploy my services. I use several machines for that. For redundancy and load balancing i'm gonna deploy one copy of each services into each machine, but i face a problem: some of these services must be working in one copy at the same time (e.g. monitoring of something which is executed by cron expression) That is to say I don't want to have several monitorings components to be run at same time, instead they have to be set up on each machine by rotation. (e.g. as here http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-..)

How could i do that the best way? What should i use for that?
thanks

Comment: rotating where a task runs does not increase it's availability. You need to make sure that it **is** running and if downtimes during failover are problematic come up with a way to have hot standbys.